# Hitting Android back button while Ajax is working (Jquery/PhoneGap)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

Let´s say i start a Ajax request as soon as the page loads. If i quickly press the back button before the Ajax has finished. The "error" event will fire off. Like it should.

But how can i know that the error was "valid" and not induced by the user hitting the back button on the android phone? Is this possible?

I´m using Jquery/PhoneGap.